# Swift - How to check if an NSDate is yesterday compare to current time?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, nsdate

I have an `NSDate` value. I need to check (compare to system current time) if that is yesterday or not. I thought that was easy because I could just pull the day value out of my `NSDate` and +1 to compare it. But soon afterward, I realized it's an inappropriate idea because what if it's end of the month, let's say July 31. And next day is not July 32, is August 1.

What's the most effective way to check if an `NSDate` is yesterday (compare to current time)?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want to find out if it's close to 24 hours ago or just if the date is one day less, ignoring time components?

Comment: Thank you for asking this. I just want to find out if the date is one day less, not 24 hours ago. And rob's answer perfectly solved my issue. If you have a better answer, please leave it there. I'd definitely check it out!

Comment: No, his is spot-on. I was just checking to be sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As of iOS 8.0, you can use `-[NSCalendar isDateInYesterday:]`, like this:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()

let someDate: NSDate = some date...
if calendar.isDateInYesterday(someDate) {
    // It was yesterday...
}
```

If you'll be doing this a lot, you should create the calendar once and keep it in an instance variable, because creating the calendar object is not trivial.

Comment: I did some preliminary testing and I don't believe that keeping an instance variable of `NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()` is any better than retrieving it every time. It's going to be a reference either way.

Comment: [Apparently `NSCalendar` became much less expensive to create in iOS 7 / OS X 10.9.](http://mikeabdullah.net/NSCalendar_currentCalendar.html)

Comment: Do you think NSDateFormatter did too?

Answer (score 7):

In **Swift 3/4/5** the API has changed:

```
Calendar.current.isDateInToday(yourDate)
Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(yourDate)
Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(yourDate)
```

To get the current date:

```
let now = Date()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension in Swift to check if the date is past date.

```
extension Date {
    var isPastDate: Bool {
        return self < Date()
    }

    func isYesterday() -> Bool {
        return Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(self)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let someDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(1)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    print(date.isPastDate)
}
```